# How to use interpolation in Asammdf? (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, interpolation, mdf, asammdf

I'm trying to read .mdf file and write it to .csv file.
I found irregular option(timestamps) but it had inconsistent gap.

How can I get a regular interval of time, say of 0.002s ?

My code is below.

```
from asammdf import MDF, set_global_option
import pandas as pd


set_global_option("raise_on_multiple_occurrences", False)
data = MDF('example.mdf')

df = data.to_dataframe(use_interpolation=True)
df.to_csv('result.csv')
```

[irregular gap of timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjEy0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `raster` argument https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asammdf.mdf.MDF.export